# Javascript Date can't be stored

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a strange issue with javascript : when stocking a new Date().getTime() in a certain variable, it goes to 0.

```
    console.log(new Date().getTime()); // Shows the timestamp
    p.channels[p.chann].startTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(p.channels[p.chann].startTime); // Shows 0
```

The variable p.channels[p.chann].startTime totally exists (and would otherwise show an error anyway...)

Does anyone know where this problem could come from ? Oo

Comment: Does it work if you store something else to the variable, like `1` or `"foo"`?

Comment: is `p`an object, `p.channels` an array (or object), `p.chan` a valid index (or key) and `p.channels[p.chann]` an object too?

Comment: Works just fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/s6NgS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that, my variable being an Audio element, I could create the startTime value in it, but it was set to 0 and couldn't be set to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I have a created a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/a7KyJ/) to show that this works.

```
p = {};
p.channels = [];
p.chann = 0;
p.channels[p.chann] = {};

p.channels[p.chann].startTime = new Date().getTime();

document.write(p.channels[p.chann].startTime);
```

The likely reasons for this failing would be that `p.chann` has been changed between setting and extracting the value, or `p.channels[p.chann]` hasn't been set as an object (you can test this by commenting out the line where `p.channels[p.chann] = {};`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this code works, the only issue could be the existance of `p.channels[p.chann].startTime` while you're retrieving the value, or maybe in your real code you're reading a different value (maybe `p.chann` changes meanwhile because you're in a loop or you created a closure... it's hard to tell)

```
var p = {
    chann    : 0,
    channels : [
       { startTime : 0 }
    ]    
};

p.channels[p.chann].startTime = new Date().getTime();
console.log(p.channels[p.chann].startTime); // Shows the value
```